# Chrome SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: jquery, ajax

Really confused, I can't find anything wrong!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare a variable within an object literal.  Move `pid` outside:

```
var pid = ...

$.ajax({ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a `var` statement inside of an object literal. You can only have object properties inside of an object literal, with the `key: value` format.

I think you are wanting something like this.

```
var pid = $("span#live-news:first").attr("id");
$.ajax({
  // all the AJAX options go here
});
```